# how to prevent already selected rows from automatically being unselected in c# datagrid

Tags: c#, windows-7, datagrid

I have a c# datagrid object which allows multiple selection. In Windows XP it works fine but in Windows 7, after the curser is moved out from the grid, previously selected rows (either with ctrl or shift) are reseted(unselected) after a while. In Windows XP, such thing doesn't happen, selected rows are always selected unless the user unselects.

Here is my grid:

```
        this.dgAlindiListesi.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dgAlindiListesi.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.ClipboardCopyMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 269);
        this.dgAlindiListesi.Name = "dgAlindiListesi";
        this.dgAlindiListesi.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dgAlindiListesi.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(830, 359);
        this.dgAlindiListesi.TabIndex = 1;
```

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I ran your datagrid setting in windows7. It wasn't unselected when the cursor is moved out from the grid. I think that your above code is fine, but other code has problems, such as managing mouse or focus.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in the "dgAlindiListesi.LostFocus" event callback? Maybe the lost focus is handeled differently between XP and Windows7

Comment: Thank you for the comment.none of the event is filled up.